# Should you take on a chumra if you're not sure you can maintain it?

Tags: minhag, nedarim-shevuot, stringency-chumrah, hiddur-mehudar

Should someone take on a new stringency/hiddur/optional mitzvah if he or she is not absolutely sure he and his progeny will be able to maintain it on all further occasions? In such a case, is it better to take the risk and rely on G-d's future help in order to grow one's avodah, or not to take such a risk at all?

(It would seem that taking on a new practice by a "bli neder" is the best possible option. However, it's still unclear to me how often one has to say/think "bli neder" in order to retain that status. Is it by every performance of the mitzvah? One in three? When one starts? And if there is a risk of messing up the "bli neder," should one not undertake the mitzvah?)

Comment: Offhand, no. There is an expression / *Al thei tzaddik harbeh* - loosely translated as "Don't be overly righteous". Generally, one is not required to be machmir. (Yes, I know that there are numerous mitzvot where Shulchan Aruch recommends to do so. Those are usually situations where there is doubt regarding which ruling to follow.) Otherwise, if one is machmir when he is not sure he can do it, what is his purpose of dong so, when he doesn't need to? Is he "showing off"?

Comment: @DanF Trying to increase in avodas H'... (or make a fence around the Torah/be a chosid/adopt a certain minhag for philosophical or personal reasons/numerous other possible explanations)

Comment: Maybe you should ask the parenthetical question as the main question and save the other part for after you get an answer to that

Comment: @SAH Got that. But, I think, overall, G-d is more interested in the quality and your "excitement". The 2nd aspect, I think, needs to emanate from optimism, not pessimism. If one wants  to be machmir, he should begin thinking that he will achieve the goal, not start with thinking he may fail.

Comment: "make a fence around the Torah" does not necessarily equate to being machmir. *Avot Derav Nattan* cites the mistake Adam made by making an incorrect "fence" by telling Chava that one may not touch the Tree of Knowledge, when no such prohibition was there.

Comment: @DanF So why are people machmir, then?

Comment: @SAH short answer--- It is not advisable. But, if one is sincere and pretty much certain they can handle it, and they really feel it will be a good thing in serving Hashem for various reasons...then one bli-neder at the start is fine. That way they can stop later if needed. Never "take anything on" is the usual rule. This is my opinion based on, my Rebbeim,  my Torah learning, and life experience.(Experience is a kind of knowledge you get two minutes after you really needed it. :) )

Comment: @DavidKenner Oh wow. I wonder why "they" don't tell you this.

Comment: Numerous reasons - many valid, many not. Many are machmir because they don't know that there's an easier option. They haven't thought through the nuances and just followed what someone told them to do. Others have thought through it, and, do want to increase their observance level. But, they understand why they do it, know the choices and have made a conscious choice to be machmir, expecting to succeed, and most of them do. You're asking if somene should begin being machmir while being nervous that he may fail. That's my main point of question to you and anyone who tries that. Why?

Comment: "he or she is not absolutely sure he will be able to maintain it on all further occasions": isn't that _always_ the case?